# Choose thymeleaf crud ui instead of Angular In JHipster

Tags: jhipster

In jhipster, how can I can choose **thymeleaf** crud UI instead of the default Angular for entities ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no thymeleaf crud UI in jhipster. Thymleaf is for server-rendered pages you may want to have outside the AngularJS single-page application.